# How would I isolate a string between two strings in DiscordJS?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've currently been using this script:

```
var portion = body.substring(
    str.lastIndexOf('ID Background',") + 1, 
    str.lastIndexOf('ID Theme',")
);
```

"Body" is the input, "Portion" being the output.

I'm trying to isolate text between the words strings "ID Background" and "ID Theme"
Example:

ID Background

Background information Background information Background information Background information

ID Theme

Theme information Theme information Theme information Theme information Theme information

...Et Cetera.

Expected Output:

Background information Background information Background information

Current Output:

undefined

I cannot figure out why this script is not working. I'm using this for a Discord bot (Discord.JS)

Comment: "*... this script is not working.*" It would be helpful if you shared the output of your script above, along with the output you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [RegExp capturing groups `()`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

```js
// objective: get everything in between 'start' and 'end'
const str = 'start hello how was your day end'; 

// capture everything in between the two words in parentheses
console.log(str.match(/start (.*) end/)[1]);
```

Since you're example uses line breaks, which the [special character `.`](https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot) doesn't cover, you should use [`[\s\S]`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) (`\s` is whitespace, and `\S` is anything *but* whitespace. Together, they cover everything. Also, use [optional chaining `?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so that your code doesn't throw a `TypeError` if no match is found.

```js
var portion = body.match(/ID Background *([\s\S]*) *ID Theme/)?.[1];

if (!portion) 
 // no match found...
```

Comment: While true (and correct) this answer would benefit greatly from being tailored more to the OP's specific situation.

Comment: I feel like this is fairly tailored to OP's situation. I'm showing how to get everything in between two words, which is exactly what they want. How do you suggest I improve the answer?